# bind_result error when using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, bind, fetch

I want to insert some values into the database but when I want to `fetch` the row the `bind_result()` function gives me this error: **number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement**. I know there are a lot of questions about it but none of those solved my problem.

**Code:**

```
    $b = 'b';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO article_status(osid,account_name,author,type,data,postdate) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("issss",$osid,$account_name,$log_username,$b,$data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($row);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if($row < 1){
        // Do something
    }
```

Comment: Where? Sorry I'm so tired and I'm not able to count ...

Comment: Stack Overflow's text editor is not too good sorry ...

Comment: There's nothing to bind. An `INSERT` query only returns a true/false.

Comment: @aynber good catch! we all starred at `bind_param` instead of `bind_result`..

Comment: I know I fell into that trap, @Jeff! *And* I wasn't able to count either, apparently, probably should get some rest :p

Comment: But I want to check how is there any rows  or not that's why I wanted to save it into a var (`$row`).